# Firebase returning null values

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to read data from my database into a recyclerview list.

The number of items is retrieved correctly, so my database reference is working fine, but the data comes empty.

This is the code i'm using to retrieve the data and bind it to my model class -

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);

    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);

    mButtonSend = findViewById(R.id.button_send);
    mEditTextFileName = findViewById(R.id.comment_field);

    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_too);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mcUploads = new ArrayList<>();
    mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    mDatabaseRef = 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Comments");
    mAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapterComment(PostActivity.this, 
mcUploads);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

     mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Comments upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Comments.class);
                mcUploads.add(upload);

                Log.e("ccmain", "This is my message" + mcUploads);
            }
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, databaseError.getMessage(), 
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


    mButtonSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mUploadTask != null && mUploadTask.isInProgress()) {
                Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Comment is being sent", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                uploadComment();
            }
        }
    });
}


private void uploadComment() {
    if (mEditTextFileName == null ) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Type something", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {

                Comments upload;

                //call the constructor from the Posts class in "models" package
                upload = new Comments(mEditTextFileName.getText().toString().trim());

                String uploadId = mDatabaseRef.push().getKey();
                mDatabaseRef.child(uploadId).setValue(upload);

            }
        }


}
```

Here is my RecyclerViewAdapter class -

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapterComment extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapterComment.ImageViewHolderComment> {

private Context mContext;
private List<Comments> mcUploads;

public RecyclerViewAdapterComment(Context context, List<Comments> uploads) {
    mContext = context;
    mcUploads = uploads;
}

@Override
public ImageViewHolderComment onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.comment_single_item, parent, false);
    return new ImageViewHolderComment(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ImageViewHolderComment holder, int position) {
    Comments uploadCurrent = mcUploads.get(position);
    holder.commentText.setText(uploadCurrent.getComment());
    Picasso.get().load(uploadCurrent.getProfile_p_url()).fit().centerCrop().into(holder.commentPhoto);

//LOGS
Log.e("rcc","::"+mcUploads.get(position));
Log.e("rcc","::"+uploadCurrent.getComment());
Log.e("rcc","::"+uploadCurrent.getProfile_p_url());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mcUploads.size();
}

public class ImageViewHolderComment extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView commentText;
    public ImageView commentPhoto;

    public ImageViewHolderComment(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        commentText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_content);
        commentPhoto = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_photo);
    }
}
}
```

On my bindViewHolder the data for `mcUploads.get(position)` comes correctly as well but then

```
holder.commentText.setText(uploadCurrent.getComment());
Picasso.get().load(uploadCurrent.getProfile_p_url()).fit().centerCrop().into(holder.commentPhoto);
```

both come as null

Comment Model Class :

```
package com.example.atelier.models;

import com.google.firebase.database.Exclude;

public class Comments {

private String comment;
private String profile_p_url;
private String mKey;

public Comments() {
}

public Comments(String comment) {
    this.comment = comment;
}


public String getComment() {
    return comment;
}

public String getProfile_p_url() {
    return profile_p_url;
}


public void setComment(String description) {
    this.comment = comment;
}
public void setProfile_p_url(String image_url) {
    this.profile_p_url = profile_p_url;
}


@Exclude
public String getKey() {
    return mKey;
}

@Exclude
public void setKey(String key) {
    mKey = key;
}

}
```

DB structure : (some of it has images too, but i'd be happy with just the text and then i can figure it out myself)

```
{
"Comments" : {
"-LvzF_VRJQ25bTUZK-dt" : {
  "comment" : "woooorrrkk",
  "profile_p_url" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.co..."
},
"-LvzRnxOZI6MMTMcg0Nf" : {
  "comment" : "ngsjtsjyskydkysoy",
  "profile_p_url" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis..."
},
"-LvzYP1jevJYongMxGiJ" : {
  "comment" : "kgsjiiyxkgxkt"
},
"-Lvz_5aM-kIg6qaKPFjv" : {
  "comment" : 
"jajhahahannabahhsbsbbs"
}`
```

Log returns:

```
2019-12-13 15:50:17.972 5664-5664/com.example.atelier E/rcc: 
::com.example.atelier.models.Comments@54e5ea1
2019-12-13 15:50:17.972 5664-5664/com.example.atelier E/rcc: ::null
2019-12-13 15:50:17.972 5664-5664/com.example.atelier E/rcc: ::null
2019-12-13 15:50:17.979 5664-5664/com.example.atelier E/rcc: 
::com.example.atelier.models.Comments@c4b4d02
2019-12-13 15:50:17.979 5664-5664/com.example.atelier E/rcc: ::null
2019-12-13 15:50:17.979 5664-5664/com.example.atelier E/rcc: ::null
2019-12-13 15:50:17.984 5664-5664/com.example.atelier E/rcc: 
::com.example.atelier.models.Comments@4be635f
2019-12-13 15:50:17.984 5664-5664/com.example.atelier E/rcc: ::null
2019-12-13 15:50:17.984 5664-5664/com.example.atelier E/rcc: ::null
2019-12-13 15:50:17.989 5664-5664/com.example.atelier E/rcc: 
::com.example.atelier.models.Comments@171bbc8
2019-12-13 15:50:17.989 5664-5664/com.example.atelier E/rcc: ::null
2019-12-13 15:50:17.989 5664-5664/com.example.atelier E/rcc: ::null
```

Comment: Why do you say "the data comes empty"? How do you check that? Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Comment: using LOGs, and check them on the logcat

Comment: Show us where you are using the Log statements and add the database schema.

Comment: added, thank you. notice, the logs come up 4 times, which is the same as the number of "comments" on my database, and `Log.e("rcc","::"+mcUploads.get(position));` does not return null

Comment: Where in your code have you placed those log statements?

Comment: Before the end of `onBindViewHolder` on RecyclerViewAdapter class, so they should normally not return null

Comment: Please add that code to your question.

Comment: updated the code, it's second block of code, lines 23-26

Comment: Show us the code where you pass `mcUploads` to the adapter.

Comment: add your Comment model class please

Comment: Added the model class and full PostActivity, which now shows how mcUploads passes to the adapter. `mAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapterComment(PostActivity.this, mcUploads);`

Comment: @alberkko230 Please study [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as it is proving hard to troubleshoot your problem interactively. To optimize the chances we can help efficiently your question should include the minimal, complete/standalone code with which we can reproduce the problem. Giving us many separate snippets is just not very effective, as we can't see how they relate. Try reproducing the problem in isolation, with hard-coded values, and only log statements for output, as well as many of the other hints in the link.

Comment: It's alright, i fixed it, problem was in model class (set parameter). Thank you everyone.